# Exchange Web Service displays error when collecting items from inbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I am receiving the error

> System.ArgumentException: The collection is empty.

when attempting to retrieve emails from my inbox. I am using a webform in Chrome to host this script. Below is the code block to retrieve the emails from my inbox using Exchange Web Server.

```
 try
    {
        //authenticate
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_username, _password);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(_username, RedirectionUrlValidationCallBack);

        //retrieve emails in blocks of 50
        int offset = 1;
        int pageSize = 50;
        bool moreEmails = true;

        emails.Clear();
        ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize, offset, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
        view.PropertySet = PropertySet.IdOnly;

        while (moreEmails)
        {
            findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

            foreach (var item in findResults.Items)
            {
                emails.Add((EmailMessage)item);
            }

            moreEmails = findResults.MoreAvailable;

            if (moreEmails)
            {
                view.Offset += pageSize;
            }
        }

        properties = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        properties.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emails, properties);

        Response.Write(string.Format("<strong>I've found {0} emails </strong><br/>", emails.Count()));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
```

The error comes from the line `service.LoadPropertiesForItems(emails, properties);`

There are emails in my inbox so I'm not sure as to why this error is occurring. Any help/direction is appreciated!

Comment: @mjwills `emails.Count()` returns 0. There is a weird thing that's happening where EWS recognises that there are items in my inbox and performs like it's supposed to, so I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: That is **very bad**. If you get two concurrent requests, they are going to see each other's mails (and / or cause the situation you are seeing). Please move that declaration inside the function. Does that help? After doing that, what is the value of `emails.Count()` and `view.Offset` when the exception occurs?

Comment: @mjwills I'm still getting the same values returned for `emails.Count()` and `view.offset` with the declaration inside the function.

Comment: Why are you setting `offset` to 1 rather than 0?

Comment: @mjwills before I wasn't getting the correct number of emails, and setting offset to 1 and pagesize to 50 seemed to work. However that being said, setting this to 0 now seems to have this working so thanks for getting me there!